# Joint p.d.f and independence

Tags: probability-distributions

I kinda remember there is a result like this from Probability theory, but I forgot how to prove it. Is there a formal name for it? Can someone kindly provide me with the proof or a link please

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ with density $f$ are independent if and only if there exist $g$ and $h$ such that $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for (almost) every $(x,y)$ in R×R.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the name of this theorem.

---

Let us assume that $X,Y$ are independant.
Let $a,b$ be two positive functions.

$$
E(a(X)b(y)) = \int a(x)b(y) f(x,y) dx \ dy 
$$

- Now if $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ is a factorization (a.e.)
  with $\int h(y) dy = 1$, then
  $$
  Ea(X) =\int a(x) g(x) h(y) dx \ dy = 
  \int a(x) g(x) dx 
  $$hence $g$ is a version of the density of $X$ (and the same for 
  $h$ and $Y$) and $g(x) = \int f(x,y) dy$ and $h(y) = \int f(x,y) dx$.
- Let us write the independance:
  $$
  E(a(X) b(Y)) = Ea(X) Eb(Y)
  \\
  \int a(x)b(y) f(x,y) dx \ dy 
  = \int a(x) g(x) dx
  \times \int b(y) h(y) dy
  = \int a(x)b(y) g(x)h(y) dx\ dy
  $$using Tonelli theorem (all is positive). As it is true for every 
  $a,b$ positive valued, 
  $$
   f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)
  $$almost everywhere.